# Apache VirtualHost with ProxyPass to node.js server refuses to work ('Could not resolve host name')

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, node.js, proxypass

I'm running local Apache on my mac for development, and also have node.js server running at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`.

I use `.dev` domain for Apache projects and would like `.node` domain to redirect to node.js server. I have virtual hosts set up as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *.dev:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/www/sites/%1/wwwroot"
    ServerName sites.dev
    ServerAlias *.dev
    UseCanonicalName Off
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *.node:80>
    ServerName sites.node
    ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:8000"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:8000"
</VirtualHost>
```

However, when I try to apply these settings, I get the error:

```
[core:error] [pid 8594] (EAI 8)nodename nor servname provided, or not known: 
AH00547: Could not resolve host name *.node -- ignoring!
```

I should note that `.dev` domain works as expected, and node.js server is reachable at `http://localhost:8000/`, just not at, say, `http://test.node/`.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my own problem, and here’s what was being done wrong here:

1. I should have made sure that the custom domain actually resolves to `localhost`.

For homebrew dnsmasq on mac, this will do the trick:

```
echo 'address=/.no/127.0.0.1' > $(brew --prefix)/etc/dnsmasq.conf
```

And then OS X should be told to look up custom domain locally:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "nameserver 127.0.0.1" > /etc/resolver/no'
```

2. VirtualHost rule for proxy redirect should appear as soon as possible in the configuration file. Otherwise, Apache might redirect your custom domain request to `localhost` without appending the custom port `:8000`.

Like this:

```
<VirtualHost *.no:80>
    ServerName sites.no
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:8000/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:8000/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *.dev:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/www/sites/%1/wwwroot"
    ServerName sites.dev
    ServerAlias *.dev
    UseCanonicalName Off
</VirtualHost>
```

3. Custom domain `.node` is not currently a valid top-level domain, [according to IANA](http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt). Changing it to something valid, like `.no`, prevents Safari from initiating Google search on requests such as `test.no`. (However, say goodbye to the real `.no` sites out there.)

And that’s it.

Comment: @AbrahamBrookes My friend, in this five year-old question I was answering to my own self, and thus was ironically belittling my own perceived lack of intelligence :) I agree that the fact that I was talking to myself was not immediately obvious, so I probably should have refrained from irony. I don’t remember this question too well, but I hope I explained my own mistake more or less comprehensively, and the reply was helpful, if not well worded. Cheers!

Comment: Re-read my answer, and cringed :) Edited it to remove the excessive self-sarcasm.

Comment: Nice one, I've deleted my comment now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *.dev:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/www/sites/%1/wwwroot"
    ServerName sites.dev
    ServerAlias *.dev
    UseCanonicalName Off
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *.node:80>
    ServerName sites.node
    ProxyRequests on
    RewriteEngine on
    <Proxy *>
             Order deny,allow
             Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:8000"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:8000"
</VirtualHost>
```

How does this work?

Comment: Sadly, the same thing happens. For testing purposes I commented out the working `<VirtualHost *.dev:80>`. It seems, the error pops up with any domain I put in the form of `*.xxx:80`. It's almost as if `*.dev:80` is the only option that works.